# CUDA programming

Tags: cuda

I am new to CUDA. I had a question on a simple program, hope someone can notice my mistake.

```
__global__ void ADD(float* A, float* B, float* C)
{
   const int ix = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
   const int iy = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;

   if(ix < 16 && iy < 16)
   {
      for(int i = 0; i<256; i++)
      C[i] = A[ix+iy*16] + B[ix+iy*16] + C[i]; // << I wish to store all in C
   }
}

extern "C" void cuda_p(float* A, float* B, float* C)
{
    float* dev_A;
    float* dev_B;
    float* dev_C;
    cudaMalloc((void**) &dev_A,  sizeof(float) * 256);
    cudaMalloc((void**) &dev_B,  sizeof(float) * 256);
    cudaMalloc((void**) &dev_C,  sizeof(float) * 256);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_A, A, sizeof(float) * 256, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_B, B, sizeof(float) * 256, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_C, C, sizeof(float) * 256, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    ADDD<<<16,16>>>(dev_A,dev_B,dev_C);
    cudaMemcpy(A, dev_A, sizeof(float) * 256, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(B, dev_B, sizeof(float) * 256, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(C, dev_C, sizeof(float) * 256, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
 cudaFree(dev_A);
 cudaFree(dev_B);
 cudaFree(dev_C);
}
```

Comment: You're mallocing dev_B twice and not dev_C? That would probably crash the program. Are you seeing a crash, or wrong results, or something else?

Comment: Also you're writing to C[i] with many threads at once. I'm fairly sure that's a bad idea. I remember seeing a section on threaded accumulation in one of the CUDA presentations online and they did it very differently. Aren't there accumulation operations provided in the SDK?

Comment: mistyped the C... anyway you are right .. but i dont know the thread accumlation. what problem should i google?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Are you sure about kernel launch configuration? In your code you try to start some unknown function `ADDD`. And your execution configuration is: gridDim = (16, 0, 0) and blockDim = (16, 0, 0). So in your kernel blockIdx.x = [0..16) and threadIdx.x = [0..16). If I understood you right, then

   `ix = threadIdx.x;
   iy = blockIdx.x;`

   Read about it in CUDA Programming Guide (Appendix B.15).
2. But it's not only one mistake. When you accumulate values in `C[i]` you have a race condition. 16 threads (1 warp) simultaneously read `C[i]`, add some value (`A[ix+iy*16] + B[ix+iy*16]`) and write the results back to `C[i]`. You should use atomic add operations (CUDA Programming Guide, Appendix B.11.1.1) or redesign your kernel to maximize memory coalescing (CUDA C Best Practices Guide 3.2.1) because atomics are very-VERY slow...

Comment: I would like to use atomic add. But my graphic card GTS8800 does not support. As I had searched some examples and tried on my desktop.

Comment: It doesn't support atomics because of compute capability 1.0 (see Table A-1 in Programming Guide + overview in Appendix G).

Maybe you need to look to the algorithm at different angle? 

 1. Sum all elements in A (e.g. http://bit.ly/bKMjtP) -> `Sum_A`;
 
 2. Sum all elements in B -> `Sum_B`;
 
 3. `Sum_AB = Sum_A + Sum_B`;
 
 4. Map function `C[i] += Sum_AB` to each element in C.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I am working on ray-triangle intersection, first I had finished the CUDA kernel on each thread using 1 ray intersect each triangles. But its slow to load triangles all the time. Therefore, I am trying using triangle to intersect all rays, the problem I got is that I can't build an array which is sharing within all threads. like C here

Comment: In that case you could use a technique from n-body simulations or simply read this: http://bit.ly/9TDByC

Answer (score 4):

Your primary issue is that the core of your kernel doesn't make sense. What you have is:

```
for(int i = 0; i<256; i++)
      C[i] = A[ix+iy*16] + B[ix+iy*16] + C[i]; // << I wish to store all in C
```

This is going to have each thread to through and read every entry in C, add its own part of A and B to it, and write it back. Since each thread is doing this at the same time, they're going to step on each other. If you really want **every** entry in C to be the sum of **all** entries in A and **all** entries in B, you want to make each thread responsible for a certain entry in C:

```
for(int i = 0; i<256; i++)
      C[ix+iy*16] += A[i] + B[i];
```

If instead you want every entry in C to be the sum of the **corresponding** entries in A and B, which seems more likely, then you would get rid of the loop, and your kernel would look like:

```
__global__ void ADD(float* A, float* B, float* C)
{
   const int ix = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
   const int iy = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;

   if(ix < 16 && iy < 16)
   {
      C[ix+iy*16] = A[ix+iy*16] + B[ix+iy*16];
   }
}
```

Each thread grabs one entry from A and one from B, and writes one entry in C.

Your secondary issue is that you're launching the kernel wrong. You're doing:

```
ADDD<<<16,16>>>(dev_A,dev_B,dev_C);
```

This launches a 1x16 grid of blocks of 1x16 threads each (of the typo'd kernel). If you want to have your threads positioned in 2 dimensions (using both the x and y indexes), you need to use `dim3` as your size specifier type. Something like:

```
// Use a grid of 4x4 blocks
dim3 gridSize;
gridSize.x = 4;
gridSize.y = 4;

// Use blocks of 4x4 threads.
dim3 blockSize;
blockSize.x = 4;
blockSize.y = 4;

// Run a 4x4 grid of blocks, each with 4x4 threads.
// So you end up with a 16x16 group of threads, matching your data layout.
ADD<<<gridSize,blockSize>>>(dev_A,dev_B,dev_C);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's my problem that i didn't ask correctly.
What i am looking is how to manage the shared memory for C, as it will collapse when multiple thread reading same location.

Comment: You can have simultaneous reads from the same location just fine; it's simultaneous *writes* or *updates* that are the problem. Also, what do you mean by "manage the shared memory"? The term "shared memory" has a certain specific meaning in CUDA, and you aren't using it.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using atomicAdd, you can allocate shared memory and write the value into shared memory, then add them, and write out. Note that do not tried to use shared memory atomicAdd, it is even slower than global memory's atomicAdd. Only shared memory's int value atomicAdd is faster than global's atomicAdd. Also notice, write into shared memory should avoid bank conflict. Actually my test shows using shared memory will increase the algorithm faster 1-5% than atomicAdd. But try syncwrap can be even faster!

In general, my suggestions are:

1. Using shared memory instead of atomicAdd
2. Using syncwrap() than syncthread() (need special design)

And you might enjoy a 5-10% increase in speed.

Comment: Modern GPUs are now able to perform a block reduction efficiently (by the hardware) so that shared memory is not faster. Doing a local reduction can still be useful but it can also be done with atomics. In addition, I did not see any speed up while using a very optimized shared-memory alternative code on my Nvidia 1660S GPU. Also note that atomicAdds are more flexible than manual reduction, especially when there are warp divergences (not to mention the code is also far much simpler).

Comment: Well, you are right~ Using the shared memory might have....similar outcome.... I am writing a matmul algorithm myself in CUDA, and I have an improvement from 305ms=> 295ms from atomicAdd to shared memory. Yes, I can not guarentee shared memory to reduce is faster than atomicAdd. Definitely this is related to your algoritm design.